# SQL query to obtain totals and subtotals

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

The query works fine but I'm just intrigued to know if there is a cleaner solution. The data are results from a survey and I'm obtaining the counts per question within a zone and an overall zone count.

```
With Cte1 (ZoneId, QuestionId, Count1)
AS
(
    Select 
        tz.ZoneId, 
        qn.QuestionId,
        Count(1) as Count1
    From 
        Customers cust 
        Inner Join Shops td on td.ShopCode = cust.ShopCode
        Inner Join Zones tz on tz.Id = td.SlsZone
        Inner Join Responses res on res.SampleId = cust.SampleId
        Inner Join QstNodes qn on qn.QuestionId = res.QstNodeId
    Where 
        Event >= 201201 And Event <= 201212
    Group BY 
        tz.ZoneId, qn.QuestionId
)
SELECT 
    ZoneId,
    QuestionId
    Count1, 
    (
        SELECT SUM(Count1)
        FROm Cte1 as innercte
        Where innercte.ZoneId = outercte.ZoneId 
    )
    as ZoneTotal
FROM    
    Cte1 outercte
```

Comment: The answer to your question is `rollup`, but that depends on the database that you are using.

Comment: @Gordon Linoff. Rollup was the the answer to my question. thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using [`OVER`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189461.aspx), you can do it in one pass:

```
With Cte1 (ZoneId, QuestionId, Count1, sum1, rn)
AS
(
    Select 
        tz.ZoneId, 
        qn.QuestionId 
      , COUNT(1) OVER(PARTITION BY tz.ZoneId, qn.QuestionId) AS "Count1"  
      , COUNT(1) OVER(PARTITION BY tz.ZoneId) AS "Sum1"
      , row_number() OVER(PARTITION BY tz.ZoneId, qn.QuestionId order by ShopCode) AS "rn"
    From 
        Customers cust 
        Inner Join Shops td on td.ShopCode = cust.ShopCode
        Inner Join Zones tz on tz.Id = td.SlsZone
        Inner Join Responses res on res.SampleId = cust.SampleId
        Inner Join QstNodes qn on qn.QuestionId = res.QstNodeId
    Where 
        Event >= 201201 And Event <= 201212
)
SELECT *
FROM    
    Cte1 outercte 
where 
    rn = 1;
```

Comment: Answers should review the original code, not just present a code snippet.

Comment: @Jamal That is not a snippet.  That is complete code.   Check my SQL related rep on stackoverflow.

Comment: What I mean is, answers here shouldn't just contain code.

Comment: @Jamal If that intro is not enough feel free to delete

Comment: Good enough for me.

Answer (score 3):

how about using `CASE`

```
SELECT  tz.ZoneId,
        qn.QuestionId,
        SUM(CASE WHEN Event >= 201201 AND Event <= 201212
                THEN 1 
                ELSE 0
            END) as Count1,
        COUNT(*) AS ZoneTotal
FROM    Customers cust
        INNER JOIN Shops td
            ON td.ShopCode = cust.ShopCode
        INNER JOIN Zones tz
            ON tz.Id = td.SlsZone
        INNER JOIN Responses res
            ON res.SampleId = cust.SampleId
        INNER JOIN QstNodes qn
            ON qn.QuestionId = res.QstNodeId
GROUP   BY tz.ZoneId, qn.QuestionId
```

**UPDATE 1**

The following illustrated on the demo has different records but that thought is the same.

- [SQLFiddle Demo Link](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/e5c70/1)